Can phosphine oxides and DMSO be used instead of Me3NO for metal carbonyl decarbonylation
One professor mentioned this, but did not provide a source. I couldn't find anything like this in the literature either. Is it even true or was it simply a mistake? If it is in fact true, I will appreaciate any links to the sources.

They're much milder oxidisers, but it may be possible.

@Mithoron that's what he said, but could you maybe provide specific literature sources? So far, none of my Reaxys and Scopus searches turned up anything...
